# Determine if there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that for all sufficiently large positive integers $n,$ $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} r(2020^n, i) > C n^2$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

For positive integers $a, b,$ let $r(a, b)$ be the unique integer $c$ so that $0 \le c \le b-1$ and $b | a-c.$

Determine if there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that for all sufficiently large positive integers $n,$ $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} r(2020^n, i) > C n^2$

**I was able to prove for $Cn$ and here a considerably stronger bound has been proven.**
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c594864h2030929p14320938

**But still for the original question I have no clue so I will appreciate if someone could help**

Comment: $r(a,b)$ is called $a\bmod b$ around these parts.

Comment: Someone pls help